# Проблема с LeaderBoard в unity android, до набора очков все работает, после нет, как исправить?

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android

Суть в том, что в начале не заходила в акаунт, после удалось это решить,
теперь проблема с LeaderBoard, до набора очков он спокойно туда заходит, но стоит хоть одно очко набрать, выдает ошибку: Произошла неизвестная ошибка.

Использую CloudOnce.

Сталкивался ли кто с подобным? Если да, то как вы решали?

[image]

Вот код. Вроде весь что взаимодействет с LeaderBoard

```
   void Start()
    {
        Screen.sleepTimeout = SleepTimeout.NeverSleep;

        Cloud.OnInitializeComplete += CloudOnceInitializeComplete; ///
        Cloud.Initialize(false, true); 
    }

    public void CloudOnceInitializeComplete()
    {
        Cloud.OnInitializeComplete -= CloudOnceInitializeComplete;
    //Debug.LogWarning("Initialized");
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        FileStream file = null;

        try
        {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            file = File.Create(Application.persistentDataPath + "/GameData.dat");
            if (data != null)
            {
                data.setHiScore(hiScore);
                data.setIsMusicOn(isMusicOn);
                data.setIsGameStartedFirstTime(isGameStartedFirstTime);

                bf.Serialize(file, data);

                ////////////
                Leaderboards.SCORE.SubmitScore(hiScore);

                ////////////
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            if (file != null)
            {
                file.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Автор, Решили проблему? Если да, расскажите как...